# How do you make a cookie to be used in a Firefox session?

Tags: firefox, cookies, session-cookies

I know that cookies are stored in the `cookies.sqlite` database, but apparently Firefox does not use this for when in session.

What I am trying to do is create a cookie on my PC (manually) and have Firefox use it when it navigates to my website (hosted on my PC). So, how do I make a cookie that Firefox can use when it is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to use an add-on such as [Cookies Manager+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/) or [Advanced Cookie Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-manager/).